# SLS Block 2: Original thrust

Tags: booster, artemis-program, ssme

In older graphics depicting the evolution of the SLS vehicle, it states that the Block 2 upgrade was to produce 11.9 million lbs of thrust. At some point in the last few years, however, this has quietly been updated to a more reasonable 9.5 million lbs. Quite the difference. How did NASA originally intend to fulfil the original thrust requirement? Was it a mistake?[image]

Comment: They intended to change the SRB's at some point and I guess they have bailed back out.

Comment: I would guess it has to do with the originally planned completely new boosters versus the currently planned "Booster Obsolescence Life Extension" boosters (BOLEs).

Comment: Yeah, notice the change in the booster graphics at the 11.9M point.